# A question in compactifications in topology

Tags: calculus, general-topology, compactification

I have been taking a course on topology this semester and I need help in this particular exercise.

> Prove that the function $f: (0,1)\to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)= \sin(1/x)$ cannot be extended to a continuous function with domain $[0,1]$.

We have studied 1 point compactifications but here 2 points are being added. I am unable to think of which result to use and would very much appreciate hints.

I am doing masters level course but first course.

Comment: Notice that the point $x=1$ does not have any discontinuity, so you can define an easy continuous extension with only problems at $x=0$.

Comment: Suppose you have such an extension. Then $f(0)=\lim_{x\to 0+} f(x)$, but that limit does not exist.

Comment: This has nothing to do with compactications of $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$1$ is irrelevant, there also is no extension to $[0,1)$, e.g.

Consider the sequences $a_n = \frac{1}{\pi n}$ and $b_n = \frac{1}{2\pi n + \frac{\pi}{2}}$ in $(0,1)$.